# Database Mail - Mail configuration information could not be read from the database - No Exception

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

I've been trying for hours to get Database Mail working on SQL Server 2008 R2 and have reached what seems like a dead end.

I have completed the Database Mail Configuration tool, made sure that SQL Brower is turned on and followed all the steps in the Troubleshooting Database Mail Books Online.

When I run `SELECT * FROM sysmail_event_log`, all I get in the description column is

**Mail configuration information could not be read from the database.**

I've tried Googling this, but most of the matches are from people who have the luxury of an exception stack.  I don't get any exception to work with.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around for far too long I had the inspiration to run SQL Profiler, capturing all errors (don't know why I didn't think of that earlier!).

During the Send Test Mail process it revealed that

**The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sysmail_help_configure_sp', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.** against System\NT AUTHORITY

So I added a bunch of permissions to that user, and suddenly everything works!

My NT AUTHORITY user now has following permissions in the **msdb** database:

- Member of the DatabaseMailUserRole

EXECUTE permission for the following:

- dbo.sp_ProcessResponse
- dbo.sp_readrequest
- dbo.sysmail_configure_sp
- dbo.sysmail_help_account_sp
- dbo.sysmail_help_admin_account_sp
- dbo.sysmail_help_configure_sp
- dbo.sysmail_help_configure_value_sp
- dbo.sysmail_help_principalprofile_sp
- dbo.sysmail_help_profile_sp
- dbo.sysmail_help_profileaccount_sp
- dbo.sysmail_help_profileaccount_sp
- dbo.sysmail_help_profileaccount_sp
- dbo.sysmail_help_profileaccount_sp

Comment: If you have nothing of consequence (apart from your new Database Mail) setup in your msdb database you could recreate it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below link :

http://www.practicalsqldba.com/2012/03/sql-server-2005-database-mail-stopped.html?showComment=1463171213768#c7726740071461349854

Updating the stored procedure `sysmail_help_admin_account_sp` in **msdb** resolved the issue.

Comment: Don't just rely on the OP visiting the link. One day the link will be bad. Add more precise instructions in your answer please!